# Matlab 'load' figure objects from '.mat' file opens plot window

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-load

Why does MATLAB open a plot window when I load a `.mat` file that contains a figure inside an `struct`?

The problem that I am facing is that I have the output of an optimization algorithm as a collection of `.mat` files. Each `.mat` file contains the state of each generation of the algorithm in a form of a single `struct`. The state structure has (among other variables) a field of type `matlab.ui.Figure`. Now, whenever I try to load any of these files with the `load` command, a plot window opens automatically.

[image: MATLAB Workspace]

Is there any way to stop MATLAB from from opening this plot window?

I am using MATLAB 2015rb.

Comment: AFAIK, this strange behavior was added in recent MATLAB versions. Since [`.fig` files are actually `.mat` files](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/fig-files-format), `load(filename,'-mat')` might just work... If this solution works for you, I can post it as an answer.

Comment: @Dev-iL Thank you for the response. I tried your solution but unfortunately it did not work. Thank you any way.

Comment: Ok, next idea - did you try loading the variable you want using [`matfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matfile.html)?

Comment: @Dev-iL Yes and it did not work again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason that it is displaying a figure is because if you look closely at your `state` structure, there is a `figure` object stored in there. When you load this graphics object (or any object, really) from a file, MATLAB will reconstruct the object. The defined behavior for loading a figure (it's `loadobj` method) is to open the figure.

This is a recent issue because older versions of MATLAB stored graphics handles as simply a number and when loading a graphics handle from file, MATLAB had no way of knowing that it was supposed to be a figure so it would just parse it as a number and move on without displaying a new figure window.

Unfortunately since your `figure` handle is nested within a `struct` there is no easy way to *not* load it. Probably the easiest thing to do would be to just delete the figure object right after loading the file (since you have the handle already).

```
data = load('filename.mat', 'state');
delete(data.state.hFigure);
```

And if you really don't like the figure poping up even for a second, you can set the default figure `Visible` property to `'off'` prior to loading and then reset it afterwards.

```
% Determine what the visibility was
prev = get(0, 'DefaultFigureVisible');

% Make it so figures don't appear
set(0, 'DefaultFigureVisible', 'off')

% Load data and delete the figure
data = load('filename.mat', 'state');
delete(state.hFigure);

% Reset the visibility
set(0, 'DefaultFigureVisible', prev)
```

Another potential solution (which would not require you to know where the `figure` handles are in your struct) is to overwrite the `DefaultFigureCreateFcn` to simply delete any figure that is created.

```
% After this point you can't create any figures or they will delete themselves
set(0, 'DefaultFigureCreateFcn', @(s,e)delete(s))

% Load your data (no figures!)
load('filename.mat', 'state')

% Allow figures to be created again
set(0, 'DefaultFigureCreateFcn', '')
```

In the future, to avoid this behavior, consider not saving any graphics  handles within your .mat files. They are very large objects and MATLAB actually will issue a warning when saving one to a file as it is not recommended.

> Warning: Figure is saved in test.mat. Saving graphics handle variables can cause the creation of very large files. To save graphics
>   figures, use `savefig`.

Comment: This worked very well and my issue is solved. Thank you.

Comment: Also you can call `close(gcf)` just after loading the file. But thanks for the extended answer, I found the option to disable figure creation very useful!

Comment: @JorgeGT You *could* do that but that makes a lot of assumptions about your file (i.e. it only contains one figure) and also assumes that somehow `gcf` actually is pointing to that figure which isn't always a guarantee.

Comment: @Suever Oh of course! I meant for OP's example. That's why I really like your very general `DefaultFigureCreateFcn` solution!